# Android ActionBar is hidden with DroidGap (PhoneGap/ Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, android-actionbar, hidden

i just spent some hours on making the Actionbar visible without success:

With my RegisterActivity i collect some login data and then i start MainActivity. In RegisterActivity i have a Actionbar but not in MainActivity:

AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
    <application android:allowBackup="true"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                  >

        <activity android:name="RegisterActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
                  <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                  </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="MainActivity" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

RegisterActivity:

```
...
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("username", username);
i.putExtra("password", password);
startActivity(i);
...
```

MainActivity:

```
...
    webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl(address);
...
```

Normally there should be an Actionbar but there isn't!

just hope that someone has a solution for my problem?!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem:

My RegisterActivity extends the Class Activity! My MainActivity extends the class DroidGap from Phonegap2.5.0 (aka Apache Cordova).

I changed MainActivity so that it extends Activity and the result is that the ActionBar is visible :D

When you need DroidGap you will have to insert

```
super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true);
```

before you call:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

At the end it looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//More Code ....
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of setting the boolean property ShowTitle is using the preferences in the config.xml.

add

```
<preference name="ShowTitle" value="true"/>
```

to config.xml to enable the ActionBar on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there is no line:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in onCreate() method?

Try:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        setContentView(...);
        ...
```

or

```
...
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
...
```

Comment: didn't help! i never used `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`
tested your suggestions but no difference