# Hide android 4.1v+ status bar in phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova

How can I hide android 5.1 status bar in phonegap app? 
I tried following in `config.xml` 
 `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />` 
 
but seens it works only for android 4.0 and lower (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

Comment: try with the cordova-plugin-statusbar

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is already explained in the link you posted:
Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.1 and Higher:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Note:
Once UI flags have been cleared (for example, by navigating away from the activity), your app needs to reset them if you want to hide the bars again.
As per my understanding you will need to perform this action each time your app is resumed. So would recommend using this in the OnResume() method.

Comment: Ok, but how use it in phonegap app?

Comment: This might help you for using the phonegap app.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789199/android-actionbar-is-hidden-with-droidgap-phonegap-cordova